# Recognising a change in window size

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I trying to understand what is happening with a `Wordpress` theme that I am using, but I don't think this is a `Wordpdress` specific question.

My menu is found on the top right hand side of the page and when the window size on my computer is made smaller the menu changes to a single drop down from the middle (so it is displayed correctly on smaller devices). On inspection I can see that there are various classes that seem to handle the appearance:

```
.menu-toggle,
.main-small-navigation ul.nav-menu.toggled-on {
display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.navigation-main ul {
    display: none;
}

.menu-toggle {
background-color: #FAFAFA;
    border-top: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
    color: #1e1e1e;
.....
    }
etc etc
```

When the screen size is reduced the `main-small-navigation` class is used and all is fine. When the screen is put back however the menu is not displayed correctly (I guess the `navigation-main` class is not being used after the change).

What I am trying to figure out is how any of this might be called when you change the size of the screen. I realise this might be a vague question and possibly `Wordpress` specific but any pointers as to what I should be looking for would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well that it has nothing to do with wordpress per said, but you only need to see the theme source to understand what is going just look here: [Theme Source](https://themes.svn.wordpress.org/twentyfourteen/1.5/js/functions.js)

you will see something like this:

```
if ( _window.width() > 781 ) {
            var mastheadHeight = $( '#masthead' ).height(),
                toolbarOffset, mastheadOffset;

            if ( mastheadHeight > 48 ) {
                body.removeClass( 'masthead-fixed' );
            }

            if ( body.is( '.header-image' ) ) {
                toolbarOffset  = body.is( '.admin-bar' ) ? $( '#wpadminbar' ).height() : 0;
                mastheadOffset = $( '#masthead' ).offset().top - toolbarOffset;

                _window.on( 'scroll.twentyfourteen', function() {
                    if ( _window.scrollTop() > mastheadOffset && mastheadHeight < 49 ) {
                        body.addClass( 'masthead-fixed' );
                    } else {
                        body.removeClass( 'masthead-fixed' );
                    }
                } );
            }
        }
```

That is making those changes happen

Comment: Thanks. I have searched each file and no reference to "window.width" or even "window" can be found.

Comment: hmmm looks like is just CSS media queries with display:block and display:hide depending of windows width

Answer (score 1):

In your javascript add:

```
   if ($(window).width() < 768) { //place whatever size your want
       //do something
   }
    else {
   }
```

Comment: using jQuery remember to add the [noConflict wrappers](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers)

Comment: Thanks. I have searched each file and no reference to "(window).width" or even "window" can be found.

Comment: No, you would have to add it to your js file, and in your condition, you could do something with the relevant navigation classes.